# Call to undefined method useIncludePath()

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to learn symfony2. I was trying to install FOSUserBundle with those terminal commands (without any errors in a terminal):

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle
$ git submodule update --init
```

But after running them, my website is not working anymore and all i'm getting is this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugUniversalClassLoader::useIncludePath()
>   in
>   /var/www/Symfony/wmap/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugUniversalClassLoader.php
>   on line 41

it can be something really simple but i'm symfony2 newbie so any help will be appreciated :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with the version tagged 1.0.0:

```
cd vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle &&
git checkout origin/1.0.0
```

The *master* version may work only with the *master* version of Symfony.

Comment: the git comand gives me following error: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'checkout': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: I meant git checkout origin/1.0.0 :)

Comment: hmm i've tried that but i'm getting following error: `error: pathspec 'origin/1.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
`. Sorry for those silly questions but git is also quite new thing to me hehe

Comment: i've also tried `git checkout 1.0.0`, the result was `Previous HEAD position was 2e186c5... Merge pull request #354 from johannes/patch-1
HEAD is now at 67300de... Fixed validation tests
` and i'm not quite sure what does it mean but the website is still not working